# Method Of Retrieving Random Value Depending on Type

Tags: java, design-patterns

I was wondering what would be the most appealing way of achieving this goal.

I have a blackbox. I give it a `supported type` and it returns a random value base off of the type.

For my supported types, I have an `enum` defined as follows:

```
public enum Types 
{
    INTEGER,
    DOUBLE,
    BIGINTEGER,
    BIGDECIMAL,
    STRING,
    BOOLEAN,
    CHAR
}
```

I thought the easiest way would be to create a static function which returns an Object based off of the `Type`

```
public static Object getRandomValue(Types type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case INTEGER:
            return randomInt();
        case DOUBLE:
            return randomDouble();
        case BIGINTEGER:
            return randomBigInt();
        case BIGDECIMAL:
            return randomBigDecimal();
        case STRING:
            return randomString();
        case BOOLEAN:
            return randomBool();
        case CHAR:
            return randomChar();
    }
}
```

The problem is that an additional cast would have to be made each time that I want to retrieve a random value based off of this method.

I've looked into the design patterns `abstract factory` and `factory`, and I can't decide if there's an advantage into implementing either of those. Or if there's a different design pattern that seems to be more appropriate.

Assume that all my `random` methods are defined.

Here's an example of the client:

```
public abstract class MyClass<T>
{
    protected T t;
}

public class MyIntClass extends MyClass<Integer>
{
    public MyIntClass()
    {
        t = getRandomValue(Types.Integer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, how you are going to use result of generation?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky added in an example of the client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
public <T> T getRandom(Class<? super T> type);
```

You could either map the type to the `enum` or use a `Map<Class<?>, Supplier<?>>`. I would use the map since the code would then just be:

```
public <T> T getRandom(Class<? super T> type){
   return (T) myMap.get(Type).get();
}
```

You might have to do some recursive work to allow for the `super` aspect that would allow `int` and `Integer` to use the same supplier.

Comment: What is the point of map if Java provides the overloading mechanism so that you say can call the supplier directly: `MyType var = overloadedFunction()`?

Comment: @Val Notice that I am passing in `Class<?>` not the OP's `Type` enum